# How do I unit test a function with a for loop in it?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a function like this

```
def fun1(self, p1, p2):

    #fun2 fetches data from db and creates doc_list - (return db.coll.find(query using p1 and p2), new query using p1 and p2)

    doc_list = self.fun2(p1, p2)       
    for doc in doc_list:
        self.fun3(p2, doc)
```

where `fun3` currently prints a logger.info message. I want to write a unit test for this function but I'm unclear as to how this should be refactored as it has a for loop. The end goal is to have a unit test where I can spoof the data coming from the db query function with my own hardcoded data(spoof f2 data) and possibly test all the list contents while unit testing fun1. Thanks

Comment: Closely-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10614794/1301972, albeit in a different language.

Comment: Thanks, I understand but I'd reached a point where I was no longer able to write tests. I've been refactoring the code and working my way backwards. I'd like to be able to test this so that I can continue testing all the way back to the top level calls and not worry about having to manually test some of the stuff anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) package you can either:

- Mock the class `fun1` is contained in with your custom class that overrides `fun2` and `fun3`
- Mock `class.fun2` and `class.fun3` with a `Mock(return_value=<your_mocked_return_value>)` mock. To test the proper calls, you could then use `mock.call_count` or `mock.call_args`.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately i wasn't familiar with mock when i started with the unit tests. Im already using python's unittest module